# How to use custom log handler in pytest

Tags: python, logging, pytest, rich

I would like to use `rich.logging.RichHandler` from the [rich library](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) to handle all captured logs in pytest.

Say I have two files,

```py
# library.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())


def func():
    x = {"value": 5}
    logger.info(x)
```

```py
# test_library.py
from library import func


def test_func():
    func()
    assert False
```

Running `pytest` shows the log message as expected, but I want it formatted by rich so I tried to put the following into `conftest.py`:

```py
import logging
import pytest
from rich.logging import RichHandler


@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_configure(config: pytest.Config):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(RichHandler())
```

which results in the following output:
[image]

Under "captured stdout call" the log message appears as formatted by the RichHandler but below that it appears a second time under "captured log call" which is not what I want. Instead the message below "captured log call" should be formatted by the RichHandler and should not appear twice.

Answer (score 0):

It does not perfectly answer your question however it could help getting a closest result.

1. Disable live logs: `log_cli = 0` in `pytest.ini`
2. Disable capture: `-s` flag equivalent to `--capture=no`
3. Disable showing captured logs: `--show-capture=no` (should be disabled when capture is turned off, but ...)

So by disabling live logs and by running `pytest -s --show-capture=no` you should get rid of the duplicated logs and get only rich-formatted logs.